# How to select average of two colums with same foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of matches of a game in a tournement.

Here is the mysql table:

| id | player1 | player1_score | player1_rating | player2 | player2_score | player2_rating | tourney_id | round |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9 | 1.05 | 2 | 3 | 5.34 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5.21 | 4 | 9 | 3.34 | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 9 | 3.52 | 6 | 2 | 5.24 | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 9 | 6.23 | 3 | 0 | 4.74 | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 8 | 9.43 | 4 | 9 | 1.23 | 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 9 | 3.41 | 5 | 7 | 6.23 | 5 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 9 | 5.22 | 4 | 2 | 2.43 | 5 | 3 |
| 8 | 2 | 3 | 4.21 | 3 | 9 | 5.22 | 5 | 3 |
| 9 | 5 | 1 | 7.31 | 6 | 9 | 3.43 | 5 | 3 |

How can I get the average player ratings for each individual player in a particular tourney?
Please note, there's two columns with player ids (player1, player2)

Comment: First specify the calculation for `average player ratings`

Comment: it's the basic average calculation.. (sum of x fields / x)

Comment: Right so which fields do you want to sum?

Comment: Have a look at the `UNION ALL` operator. Basically, you'd combine two queries, one selecting `player1_rating` and the other `player2_rating`. Then you just get the average of the combined output.

Comment: player1_rating or player2_rating, whichever belongs to the selected player

Comment: @El_Vanja could you give me a query example pls?

Comment: How about a pivot query? Where is the db fiddle for us to play with?  Your db sample data should include more than one tournament for accuracy's sake.  Can you even produce pseudo-code?  I reckon your db table needs to be redesigned to make things simpler.

Comment: It is also useful to show the result you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements (Even though you do not give us your expected results), I assume your code should be like this:

```
 SELECT (SELECT SUM(player1_rating) / COUNT(DISTINCT player1)
            FROM your_table GROUP BY player1) as avg_player1, 
           (SELECT SUM(player2_rating) / COUNT(DISTINCT player2) FROM your_table 
           GROUP BY player2) as avg_player2
    FROM your_table
```

Comment: "Do this" answers miss the opportunity to be truly helpful.  A good, complete answer will explain the snippet with the intention to educate the OP and future researchers.

Answer (score -1):

I revised the query to:

```
SELECT player_id
    , tourney_id
    , avg_player_rating = SUM(player_rating) / SUM(cnt)
FROM (

    SELECT player_id = player1
        , tourney_id
        , player_rating = SUM(player1_rating)
        , cnt = COUNT(*)
    FROM tournament
    GROUP BY tourney_id, player1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT player_id = player2
        , tourney_id
        , player_rating = SUM(player2_rating)
        , cnt = COUNT(*)
    FROM tournament
    GROUP BY tourney_id, player2

) AS a
GROUP BY player_id, tourney_id
```

and this will give the result:

```
player_id   tourney_id   avg_player_rating
----------  ----------   --------------------
 1           5            4.1666
 2           5            6.3266
 3           5            4.6450
 4           5            2.3333
 5           5            5.6866
 6           5            4.3350
```

I hope that this is the result that you are looking for.

Comment: This doesn't achieve what is asked. This will give two separate averages, and of *all* players in the tournament, not the average of *every* player.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I need.

Comment: Sorry I did not seem to properly understand the question. I did a revision on the query though. I hope that this is the result that you are looking for.